# Function with input (a,b,c) that results in output (x,z,y)

Tags: arrays, blender

So I'm working on a process that will allow me to calculate subobject normals for models I am putting into a game. Basically, I know how to calculate them but I need to create a function that can use this bit of code.

```
local sin, asin = math.sin, math.asin
local deg, rad = math.deg, math.rad
math.sin = function (x) return sin(rad(x)) end
math.asin = function (x) return asin(deg(x)) end       --Makes math.sin read in degrees instead of radians

x = function (sin (a))
z = function (sin (b))
y = function (sin (c))

d = {a, b, c}
end

e = {x, z, y}
end

repeat
print("Enter a value for x:")
a = io.read("*number")          -- read a number
print(math.sin(a))
print("Do you want to repeat? Type 1 to repeat")
a = io.read("*number")
until a ~= 1
```

The way it works is that the sine of the angle that the subobject was rotated becomes the normal value on that axis. (z = b because Blender operates in X-Y horizontal and the game is in X-Z horizontal)

Basically, I am looking for a function the allows me to input "array d" and get the output displayed as "array e" instead of that single output function. a, b, and c are variables, not constants.

Answer (score 0):

A function in python can be defined as -

```
def myfunc(a,b,c):
    x = sin (a)
    z = sin (b)
    y = sin (c)
    return x,y,z
```

or you can input an array -

```
def myfunc(arr):
    x = sin (arr[0])
    z = sin (arr[1])
    y = sin (arr[2])
    return {x,y,z}
```

Notice that you can return multiple numbers stored in different ways, depending on your needs.